# Why does the page width affect "margin-top:50%" in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

In this JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/9UMRk/

A div has a margin-top of 50%. Which I would expect to adjust to the page height.

However, if you resize the window in Firefox (3 & 4), you'll see the div's vertical positioning is affected by the page width, but not the page height.

Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does seem counter-intuitive, but is in fact in accordance to the box model for margins, which states, [in the CSS level 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties):

> **The percentage is calculated with respect to the *width* of the generated box's containing block. Note that this is true for 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well.** If the containing block's width depends on this element, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1.

And [in the CSS3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#the-margin) (more clearly IMO):

> **Note that in a horizontal flow, percentages on ‘margin-top’ and ‘margin-bottom’ are relative to the *width* of the containing block, not the height** (and in vertical flow, ‘margin-left’ and ‘margin-right’ are relative to the height, not the width).

*(Bold emphases mine.)*

Comment: Since this is standard behavior, you should expect to see the same behavior in other browsers too.

Comment: Um... wow. Am I missing something, or is that a really bizarre way to define how margin-top should work? I see webkit chose to go a completely different way with this. In Safari & Chrome, only the page height affects margin-top:50%. This seems, on the surface, to be a much more useful implementation.

Comment: The problem with defining the percent margin in terms of the parent's height is that the parent's height generally depends on the margin in question.  So in most cases it would do absolutely nothing at best...