# CSS margin-top as a function of height

Tags: css

Is it possible to set the margin-top of an element to be half its height without using an element with a fixed height?

Comment: You may need javascript for this

Comment: you could accomplish this with some jquery code.

Comment: Not without JavaScript. CSS needs to know the height to be able to set the margin.

Comment: @Nathan MacInnes: Actually, CSS can't accomplish this even if you have a fixed height; [relative margins are only calculated off the width, and not the height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386353/why-does-the-page-width-affect-margin-top50-in-firefox). (Curiously, it seems that WebKit doesn't mind, but then it violates the spec in doing so.)

Comment: @BoltClock Hmmm... didn't know that. So it's even less possible then!

Comment: It turns out that currently if you want to do it with just css you have to have both margin-top and height in px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/6qsvt/

jquery

```
    $(function() {
    // vertical align function
    $.fn.vAlign = function() {
        return this.each(function(i){
            var ah = $(this).height();
            var ph = $(this).parent().height();        
            var mh = Math.ceil((ph-ah) / 2); //var mh = (ph - ah) / 2;
            $(this).css('margin-top', mh);
            console.log(mh);
        });
    };

    $('#i').vAlign();

});
```

Comment: I'll accept this event though it's not a css-only solution - other people may find it helpful to know that the only way to do this is by using something like this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Calc may help you, but it is yet a draft. check the following link: [calc](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/03/CSS-layout-gets-smarter-with-calc)

Combining it with attr you may do fancy stuff like:

```
margin-top: calc(50% * (attr(width))
```

Comment: The current spec doesn't allow `attr()` in `calc()`. Even if it did end up allowing it later, `attr()` cannot reference a CSS property so it would be useless.

Comment: I would not recomend to use it(actually on w3c thay say these features may be dropped), I would use js, but if he/she really need to use only css, It's the only way to do it