# CSS - margin top of 50% is more than 50%

Tags: html, css

I want a child div with a op-margin via percentage. The y-position shall be 50% percent of the parent div. But it is somehow more. Why isn't it 50% ?

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73xkT/4/)

HTML

```
<div class="content">
  <header></header>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
 }

.content header {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   margin-top: 50%;
   background: red;
   position: relative;
   float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is because when it comes to top/bottom margins and paddings in percentages, the values will be taken as the fractional width of the parent element, not the height. According to the [W3C definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties):

> The [margin] percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the
>   generated box's containing block. Note that this is true for
>   'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well. If the containing block's
>   width depends on this element, then the resulting layout is undefined
>   in CSS 2.1.

This question has been addressed before in StackOverflow - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11004839/395910).

---

Suggestion: If you would want to position an element in the center vertically, you can use the following trick instead:

1. Position the child element absolutely
2. Declare dimensions for the parent, such that the parent's dimensions do not rely on those of the child
3. Position the child element 50% from the top
4. Use a nifty trick of CSS 2D translation.

Here's the modified CSS from your fiddle that works:

```
.content header {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 50%;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/73xkT/7/

Comment: What. _Why_ would _anyone_ think that a vertical margin should be calculated from the horizontal parent width. I really can't see a use case to ever warrant that being a good idea

Comment: @Bojangles You'll have to take that up with W3C :P but the postulation (see linked SO answer in my answer above) is that if we calculating top/bottom margins by height, it would lead to an infinite loop because the rendering engine will have to continuously adjust and recalculating the parent height.

Comment: @Bojangles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386353/why-does-the-page-width-affect-margin-top50-in-firefox/7386385#comment8924992_7386385 (comment on another duplicate question)

Answer (score 5):

Change child's [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) from relative to absolute. 
Instead of `margin-top` use `top`

http://jsfiddle.net/73xkT/5/

```
.content header {
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
```