# Negative margin percent not working as expected

Tags: html, css, less

Html

```
<nav class="dropdown">
    <a href="#css">CSS</a>
    <section class="drop-right align-middle">
        <a href="#grid">grid</a>
        <a href="#typography">typography</a>
        <a href="#code">code</a>
        <a href="#tables">tables</a>
        <a href="#forms">forms</a>
        <a href="#buttons">buttons</a>
        <a href="#images">images</a>
    </section>
</nav>
```

Less

```
&.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    > section {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        min-width: 14rem;
        background: @matteBlack;
        &.drop-right {
            left: 100%;
            top: 0;
            &.align-middle {
                margin-top: -50%;
            }
        }
        .clear();
    }
    &:hover {
        > section {
            display: block;
        }
    }
}
.clear() {
    &:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get a middle aligned drop right but the margin-top isn't working as expected. I expect the margin-top to be half its height. But no matter what any other value is (I have changed the left and height), margin-top remains as -109.75px. Here is an example of the computed values.

[image: Computed Values]

Comment: After doing a little bit of digging, I found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982480/how-to-set-the-margin-or-padding-as-percentage-of-height-or-parent-container). So it seems margin top and bottom aren't relative to height. I still world like to know where it is getting the 109.75px from though.

Comment: The margin is calculated as a percentage of the width of the parent element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585682/css-margin-top-of-50-is-more-than-50). I ended up replacing `margin-top: -50%;` with `transform: translate(0, calc(-50% + 25px));`. 25px being the height of the item you hover over to cause the dropdown. Now I have an almost completely centered drop right.