# html,body height 100% and body's padding-bottom doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: css, margin, padding

I have the `html, body {height: 100%;}` thing to (among other things) do a `div {position: relative; top: 80%}`.
Now I want some padding/margin/space after that `div`, right before the page's bottom edge.

The most straightforward thing I came up with, `div {margin-bottom: 3em;}`, works in Chrome, but not in Firefox (as far as I can tell, the margin starts where the body ends, at "100%", which is way above the div's bottom edge).
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xvrhmLsv/3/

A workaround might be a "media query height cascade", but I'd very much like to avoid that; plus I remember running into this behaviour more than once... Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How about using a border to get the effect you want? e.g.

```
div {
border-bottom: 3em solid white;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, i don't have a solid colored background, and with `solid transparent` the border takes the div's background color...

Answer (score 0):

The following is the CSS taken from your fiddle :

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    padding-bottom: 3em; /*does not work*/
}
div {
    background: red;
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 80%;
    margin-bottom: 3em; /*does not work in Firefox, works in Chrome*/
}
```

and the html is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    (scroll down)
    <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Actually, both `padding-bottom` and `margin-bottom` works in Chrome and also in Firefox.

The elements `html` and `body` have a height defined to `100%`, therefore their height are constrained by the height of the window. The element `<div>` has a `top` property set at `80%`. The div overflows the body, and therefore, the padding-bottom you set on the body is hidden by the `div`.

The difference comes from the `margin-bottom` set on the `div`. This margin is taken into account by both browsers, but Chrome scrolls down the the element including his bottom margin, whereas Firefox scrolls down to the bottom offset of the element's box only.

I [updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/xvrhmLsv/9/) with some opacity on the div, and borders on the elements.

**EDIT** : Firefox appear to not scroll down to the `margin-bottom` of the overflowing div because of the use of `top`. If, instead of `top: 80%;` I put `margin-top: 80%;` the `margin-bottom` is taken into account in the scroll.
See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xvrhmLsv/10/). In this last fiddle, the only change I made is to replace `top` by `margin-top`.

Comment: unfortunately, you can't just replace `top` with `margin-top`, as margins given by percentage are relative to the parent's _width_. [cf.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386353/why-does-the-page-width-affect-margin-top50-in-firefox) ... it appears to work if your viewport is roughly square :)

Comment: Indeed, the height offset of the div is not the same with `margin-top` as the value you provided is in percentage. Because your div is positioned relatively to the body, and therefore to the window, you have another quick option though. You could use the viewport height `vh` unit, with `margin-top: 80vh`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xvrhmLsv/12/)

Comment: _if_ [you can use it](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh), this works... i'll do more digging before i accept this, though.